# Centering the caption of longtable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, tabularray

I've tried to center the caption of a long table (`longtblr`) but it always appears to the left I used the package `\usepackage[justification=centring]{caption}` and `\captionsetup{justification = centering}` I almost tried everything but I didn't get the result I want.

Can anyone help me, please?

I added an example about my work

```
\docmentclass{article}
%\usepackage{??}
\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
  \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[theme=fancy,
  caption = {obtained results for the work as shown in the table below with test and M from 1 to 16.},
  label = {tab:websites},
]{
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {Q[175]Q[150]Q[175]Q[175]Q[175]},
  cells = {c},
  cell{2}{2} = {r=2}{},
  cell{4}{2} = {r=2}{},
  cell{6}{2} = {r=2}{},
  cell{8}{2} = {r=2}{},
  cell{10}{2} = {r=2}{},
  cell{12}{2} = {r=2}{},
  cell{14}{2} = {r=2}{},
  cell{16}{2} = {r=2}{},
  vlines,
  hline{1-2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18} = {-}{},
  hline{3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17} = {1,3-5}{},
}
test & test & test & test & test \\
M1   & 90   & 0.63 & 0.71 & 0.67 \\
M2   &      & 0.67 & 0.58 & 0.62 \\
M3   & 80   & 0.61 & 0.76 & 0.68 \\
M4   &      & 0.68 & 0.51 & 0.58 \\
M5   & 70   & 0.85 & 0.86 & 0.86 \\
M6   &      & 0.86 & 0.85 & 0.86 \\
M7   & 65   & 0.92 & 0.93 & 0.92 \\
M8   &      & 0.93 & 0.91 & 0.92 \\
M9   & 77   & 0.95 & 0.75 & 0.84 \\
M10  &      & 0.79 & 0.96 & 0.87 \\
M11  & 56   & 0.94 & 0.77 & 0.85 \\
M12  &      & 0.81 & 0.95 & 0.87 \\
M13  & 89   & 0.87 & 0.82 & 0.84 \\
M14  &      & 0.83 & 0.87 & 0.85 \\
M15  & 63   & 0.57 & 0.58 & 0.58 \\
M16  &      & 0.57 & 0.57 & 0.57 
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

I got this table the caption is not in the center
[image: non-centred caption for table]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Package `tabularray` has inbuilt own mechanism for captions settings on which `caption` package has not  influence. Their caption are horizontal centered by default.  If you like to overwrite this, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/698246/. Please provide an MWE (Minimal Working Example) that we can see what actually is your problem.

Comment: I edited my question as you asked.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your code so we can compile it. It should start `\documentclass{}` and end `\end{document}`. When compiled, it should produce the problem you are asking about. I've done a bit of tidying, but I don't know what packages are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It is not entirely clear, what is your problem.
- By default at `longtblr` tables the `caption` package hasn't any influence on the  caption formatting.
- Long tables, using `longtblr` has own caption mechanism which captions centered when they are shorter then table width and hang formatted when text is longer.
- For example, in the former case, your table code can be (written far more concise):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Obtained results for the test M from 1 to 16.},
  label = {tab:websites},
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = { *{5}{X[c]}},
                  cell{even[2]}{2} = {r=2}{},
                  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                  rowhead=1
                  }
test & test & test & test & test    \\
M1   & 90   & 0.63 & 0.71 & 0.67    \\
M2   &      & 0.67 & 0.58 & 0.62    \\
M3   & 80   & 0.61 & 0.76 & 0.68    \\
M4   &      & 0.68 & 0.51 & 0.58    \\
M5   & 70   & 0.85 & 0.86 & 0.86    \\
M6   &      & 0.86 & 0.85 & 0.86    \\
M7   & 65   & 0.92 & 0.93 & 0.92    \\
M8   &      & 0.93 & 0.91 & 0.92    \\
M9   & 77   & 0.95 & 0.75 & 0.84    \\
M10  &      & 0.79 & 0.96 & 0.87    \\
M11  & 56   & 0.94 & 0.77 & 0.85    \\
M12  &      & 0.81 & 0.95 & 0.87    \\
M13  & 89   & 0.87 & 0.82 & 0.84    \\
M14  &      & 0.83 & 0.87 & 0.85    \\
M15  & 63   & 0.57 & 0.58 & 0.58    \\
M16  &      & 0.57 & 0.57 & 0.57    \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- However, in cases when caption test is longer than one line and text together with caption label should be centered, you can use `caption` package and its formatting possibilities implicit by inserting `\captionof` for table caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{caption}        % <---
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0pt,
                     font = {small, sf},
                     labelfont = bf,
                    justification=centering    % or
%                     justification=centerlast
                    }
\NewTblrTheme{captionof}%   % <---
{\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}%
    {\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
     \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
    }
 \DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}%
    {\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
     \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption} (continue)}
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
  theme = captionof,        % <---
caption = {Obtained results for the test M from 1 to 16. This caption quite text, so it is split at leat into two lines},
  label = {tab:websites},
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = { *{5}{X[c]}},
                  cell{even[2]}{2} = {r=2}{},
                  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                  rowhead=1
                  }
test & test & test & test & test    \\
M1   & 90   & 0.63 & 0.71 & 0.67    \\
M2   &      & 0.67 & 0.58 & 0.62    \\
M3   & 80   & 0.61 & 0.76 & 0.68    \\
M4   &      & 0.68 & 0.51 & 0.58    \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Which produce the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it's work. I couldn't paste my work because I am using latex for documenting my thesis. So my document package is \classdocument{book}. This is my first post, and I didn't know how to shorten it. Thanks again.

Comment: @b.als, you are welcome. If answer solve your problem, and you learn how to write `tabularray` tables more efficiently, you may consider to accept ma answer (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of of answer.).

Comment: thank you so much.